# Angular 1.4 - reuse same controller in $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I am trying to use same controller on both full and mobile views using $routeProvider. Code below does not work out of the box. What am i missing?

Also i could use another idea - same controller, but different *templateUrl* based on user agent. Can i do that?

```
   $routeProvider
        .when("/details/:id", {
            templateUrl: "views/details.html",
            controller: "detailsController"
        })
        .when("/mdetails/:id", {
            templateUrl:  "views/mobiledetails.html",
            controller: "detailsController"
        })

}])
```

Comment: is it working for your first view ?

Comment: have you included `detailsController` file in `index.html`?

Comment: everything is fine when i am using 2 js files. i want to avoid copy paste.

`$routeProvider
        .when("/details/:id", {
            templateUrl: "views/details.html",
            controller: "detailsController"
        })
        .when("/mdetails/:id", {
            templateUrl:  "views/mobiledetails.html",
            controller: "mdetailsController"
        })

}])`

Comment: When you say that it does not work, do you mean that you are seeing errors in the console?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to show us the error?

Comment: **Don't** Tell us "it doesn't work" and leave it at that.
We can figure this out by the fact that you've asked the question in the first place, and without further information, we will close it for being unclear.

Comment: it works now. sorry guys, it is first time in my dev life. no idea what was wrong. it just started working

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 different controller that share the same function (the controller logic) or use 2 different controller that uses their own function but share a service with all logic inside.

Following is a sample of first case:

```js
angular.module('FunnyAnt.Examples.Routing', ['ngRoute']);

function sharedController($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Shared";
}

angular.module('FunnyAnt.Examples.Routing')
  .controller('HomeController', sharedController);

angular.module('FunnyAnt.Examples.Routing')
  .controller('AboutController', sharedController);

angular.module('FunnyAnt.Examples.Routing')
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'embedded.home.html',
      controller: 'HomeController'
    }).
    when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'embedded.about.html',
      controller: 'AboutController'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular-route.js"></script>

<div ng-app="FunnyAnt.Examples.Routing">

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="embedded.home.html">
    <h1> Home: {{ name }} </h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="embedded.about.html">
    <h1> About: {{ name }} </h1>
  </script>

  <div id="navigation">
    <a href="#/home">Home</a>
    <a href="#/about">About</a>
  </div>

  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but simple reusing also valid right?

`.when("/details/:id", {
            templateUrl: "views/details.html",
            controller: "detailsController"
        })
        .when("/mdetails/:id", {
            templateUrl:  "views/mobiledetails.html",
            controller: "detailsController"
        })`

Comment: Not sure about this, it's more correct to declare 2 separate controller and reuse a shared service or use the same function controller on both

Comment: i do not know what the heck  happened, but now all my code works with simple reuse. do not know, how to delete question though.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what happened, but everything works.

```
  $routeProvider
        .when("/details/:id", {
            templateUrl: "views/details.html",
            controller: "detailsController"
        })
        .when("/mdetails/:id", {
            templateUrl:  "views/mobiledetails.html",
            controller: "detailsController"
        })

}])
```

inside of controller I made variable is mobile (**ism**) and I am using it for extra logic

```
$scope.ism = $location.path().indexOf('/mflights') === 0;
```